# Error using component Text from ART

Tags: ios, react-native

i'm currently using react native `ART` module, and everything is ok except the Text component, but the bug is only happening in `iOS`, in `android` everything seems to work as expected.

When i try to use the Text component in iOS react trows an this error:

[Image Output Error in App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMpZd.png)

And in Xcode console output's this:

```
2016-09-20 17:17:17.663 [error][tid:main][RCTConvert.m:57] Error setting property 'frame' of ARTText with tag #7: JSON value '' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSDictionary
```

Since react native `ART` doesn't have documentation, it's very possible that I'm not doing something right, but I already read the source code and nothing is working that I try.

**Additional Information:**

- React Native version:0.33.0
- Platform: iOS
- Operating System: macOS
- Xcode: 8.0

**RnPlay** is down so i'm gonna post the code here:
https://jpst.it/NAac

As soon as the **RNplay** is up, i will update this post and put the code there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was having this error myself too, turns out that you need to provide the font property, according to this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5480)

Copied from there

```
<ARTText font={`13px "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial`} fill="#000000" x={16} y={16}>Hello</ARTText>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , right now i'm not in the project, but i will try your solution in a couple of weeks, and if works, i'm gonna assign your answer as the right one.

happy holidays :)

Comment: I got this to work on iOS but am now trying to get it to work on Android. I tried `font={'13px sans-serif}'` but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm currently displaying text but unable to change the current font size with this, no matter what value I put. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify font values this way, which works on both iOS and Android:

```
<ART.Text
  font={{
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
    fontSize: 13,
  }}
  fill="#000000"
  x={16}
  y={16}
>
  Hello
</ARTText>
```

Other attributes, as discerned from the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e9780bdc0f00364359f39e5a76a3e43eadb93a4b/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART.js#L455-L472), are:

- `fontWeight: (number | 'bold' | 'normal')`
- `fontStyle: ('italic' | 'normal')`